# unable to create t3 burstable instances with custom VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, amazon-rds

I created a custom VPC with 9 subnets, such that for 3 AZ I have 3 subnets (public, private, and persistence). It has the following configuration:

**VPC**

10.100.0.0/16

**Subnets**

```
- 10.100.0.0/24  (az1)
- 10.100.10.0/24 (az1)
- 10.100.20.0/24 (az1)

- 10.100.1.0/24  (az2)
- 10.100.11.0/24 (az2)
- 10.100.21.0/24 (az2)

- 10.100.2.0/24  (az3)
- 10.100.12.0/24 (az3)
- 10.100.22.0/24 (az3)
```

Everything seems okay, except I am unable to create any type of burstable instance within my VPC.

In the AWS web UI, if I choose a `t3.X` instance, then I am only able to choose the default VPC and my custom VPC is greyed out.

Likewise, I am unable to create an RDS burstable instance. I created a subnet group which consists of the `persistence` subnets (e.g. 1 private subnet from each AZ defined above). However, when I attempt to create the DB, I get the following error:

> Cannot create a db.t3.medium database instance because there are no availability zones with sufficient capacity for VPC and storage type : gp2 for db.t3.medium. Please try the request again at a later time.

I am able to create all other types of instances in EC2 and RDS (e.g. `m`, `r`, and `x` classes).

Does anyone know what's going on?

1. I have no other instances launched in the VPC, so I know that I have plenty of addresses.
2. I am able to launch the `tX` instance when I use the default VPC provided by AWS. It's only when I try to launch in my own instance that it fails. I assume this means the devices exist in the region/AZ, so I don't think it's a region capacity issue.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that the VPC was created with a `dedicated` tenancy, which is incompatible with `tX` instances. I changed the tenancy to `default` and everything was resolved.